# Android fetching phone number, name and photo from contacts taking too much time

Tags: android, performance, android-cursor, android-contentresolver

This code fetching contacts, name and photo from contact list but it is taking too much time in fetching all these.

So my problem is if user has more then 500 contacts then its taking to much time so how to decreasing its fetching time.

I have seen many posts on Stack Overflow but unable to find solution.

```
public void fetchContacts() {
        list = new ArrayList<PersonDetails>();

            String phoneNumber = null;
            //Uri CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
            Uri CONTENT_URI=    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
            String _ID = ContactsContract.Contacts._ID;
            String DISPLAY_NAME = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;
            String HAS_PHONE_NUMBER = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER;
            Uri PhoneCONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
            String Phone_CONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID;
            String NUMBER = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER;
            // StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

            String[] PROJECTION = new String[] {
                    ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER, };
            String SELECTION = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER
                    + "='1'";

            ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
            Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION,
                    SELECTION, null, null);

            // Loop for every contact in the phone
                if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    //Log.e("i", i + "");
                    PersonDetails personDetails = null;
                    String contact_id = cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(_ID));

                    String name = cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(DISPLAY_NAME));

                    int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor
                            .getString(cursor
                                    .getColumnIndex(HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));

                    if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {

                        // Query and loop for every phone number of the
                        // contact
                        String Phone_Projection[] = new String[] { Phone.NUMBER };
                        Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(
                                PhoneCONTENT_URI, Phone_Projection,
                                Phone_CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                                new String[] { contact_id }, null);

                        while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {

                            phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor
                                    .getColumnIndex(NUMBER));

                            // output.append("\n Phone number:" +
                            // phoneNumber);

                        }

                        phoneCursor.close();

                        if (phoneNumber != null
                                && phoneNumber.length() >= 10) {
                            Uri ur = null;
                            try {
                                Uri person = ContentUris
                                        .withAppendedId(
                                                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                                                Long.parseLong(contact_id));
                                ur = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                                        person,
                                        ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
                            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            personDetails = new PersonDetails();
                            if (name != null) {
                                personDetails.setName(name);
                            }
                            if (phoneNumber != null) {
                                //Log.e("Phone", phoneNumber);
                                personDetails.setSocialId(phoneNumber);
                            }
                            if (ur != null) {
                                //Log.e("URI", ur.toString());
                                personDetails.setPhotoUrl(ur.toString());
                            }
                            personDetails.setSocialFlag(5);
                        }

                    }
                    if (personDetails != null) {
                        list.add(personDetails);
                    }
                }

            }
            try {
                if (cursor != null) {
                    cursor.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: if we have 300 contacts in phonebook then its taking 10 second's

Comment: I think it's normal, I have almost the same thing

Comment: On this old question, it depends on where the bottleneck is - is the slow component the HTTP connection, the web server, the mobile CPU, etc?

Comment: how to effectively handle such a situation?